# Не работает конструктор копирования в шаблоне

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, конструктор-копирования

Почему следующий код работает с конструктором копирования по значению, но не с конструктор копирования по ссылке?

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    //A(const T& x) : x{x} {} // ERROR
    A(T x) : x{x} {}        // OK

    T x;
};


int main() {
    A a = "hello, world";
}
```

Comment: В Вашем коде нет конструктора копирования.

Comment: @ixSci тоесть который принемает 1 аргумент не знаю как он называется

Comment: Конструктор копирования выглядел бы как `A(const A &other) : x(other.x) {}`.

Comment: @вася: Такой конструктор называется *конструктором преобразования* или  *конструктором конверсии*.

Answer (score 3):

Итак, в Вашем коде нет конструктора копирования, но есть простой конструктор с одним аргументом. В случае если у Вас есть такой конструктор: `A(T x)`, то при вызове `A a = "hello, world";`, с помощью неявно сгенерированной инструкции выведения, тип `T` выводится как `char *`. В результате получается такой член структуры: `char* x`. В списке инициализации у Вас происходит присвоение одного указателя другому — вполне нормальная операция, поэтому ошибки нет.

Теперь рассмотрим: `A(const T& x) : x{x}`. Выведение шаблонного типа, при участии ссылки, происходит по другому; тип не «распадется» (decay), а остаётся нетронутым. Типом `"hello, world"` является `const char[13]`, соответственно у Вас получается такой член структуры: `const char x[13];`, который Вы пытаетесь инициализировать другим массивом `const char[13]`, что невозможно, отсюда и ошибка.

Т.е. во втором случае, Вы первому элементу массива пытаетесь присвоить другой массив. Но элемент массива имеет тип `char`, а ему пытаются присвоить `const char[13]`. Вы могли бы изменить синтаксис инициализации на круглые скобки: `A(const T& x) : x(x) {}`, таким образом избавившись от агрегатной инициализации, но это бы Вам всё равно не помогло т.к. массивы так инициализировать всё равно нельзя. И Вы бы снова получили ошибку, только другую.

Comment: ... то при вызове A a = "hello, world"....  вы не говорите о том, что не существует тип А, а сушествует шаблонный тип,  поэтому тут отсутствует аргумент шаблона

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, не нужно там ничего указывать. Тип сам выводится, и я об этом в первом параграфе написал.

Answer (score 0):

`A a = "hello, world"`; тут еще одна ошибка, кроме того, что сказано в предыдущем ответе, добавлю, что  ваша структура шаблонная, поэтому нужно указать аргумент шаблона (инстанцирровать). Вот еслибы вы написали, например:

```
 A<std::string> a = std::string("hello, world");
```

то все бы заработало...